# Extracting text from image in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to extract the text from image (Image having text written in it). Is it possible using objective c ?

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Since Objective-C is a pretty flexible language I think it would be possible to do this in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a google sponsored project called Tesseract that might fit your needs.
Check this out: [Tesseract Demo](https://github.com/nolanbrown/Tesseract-iPhone-Demo)

I have no personal experience with it though. Good luck!